# SPFX 1.6 msGraphClient error on SharePoint app

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I created a SharePoint Framework 1.6 webpart which uses the MSGraphClient. On all browsers (tested with IE11, Edge, Chrome on laptop. Tested with Chrome, Edge, Samsung browser on cell phone ) this is working as expected: information from Graph is received.

However, when I open the site with the webpart in the SharePoint mobile app the webpart receives an error:

"AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge, and the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint (login.microsoft.com)."

Is anyone having similar issue on SharePoint app?

Here is the code snippet:

```
this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient().then((client: MSGraphClient) => {
  client.api("/me").get().then( (userInfo: any) => {
    alert(userInfo.displayName);
  }, (error => {
    alert(error.message);
  }) );
});
```

Comment: Reported here as well: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2521 follow up there

Answer (score 1):

I think I resolved the problem on "Internet Explorer", this issue is because "https://login.microsoftonline.com" is not added to "IE security zone", so the error says: "the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint"

Steps:
On IE, open "Internet Options" and you have to ensure both sites are on the same security zones "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com" and "https://login.microsoftonline.com", after that close all sessions and restart it

It worked for me! 
Diego A. Campo
diegoc@e-deas.com.co

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround that might not help everyone:
I visited https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and logged in using my credentials.

After that - it started working again.

I'm pretty sure deleting all browser data and cookies, then re-opening the browser and signing in again would have fixed it but I hate doing that... lol